# KSH script having trouble reading in variables line by line

Tags: scripting, ksh

For starters, I'm not the most advanced scripter. I was asked to create a script that would search through a directory for print files older than 14 days and move them to an archive directory. There are several directories that will have corresponding archive directories with them. To test this, I created two text files that would have the source directory and the destination directory. Things went fine when there was only one directory path in each file. However, when I added another directory path to each file, the script moved the first archive folder into the second archive folder.

The files found in the first line of `printdirs.txt` should be moved to the path found in the first line of `archivedirs.txt`. Then the loop runs again and the files found in the path on the second line of `printdirs.txt` should be moved to the path found on the second line of `archivedirs.txt` and so forth.

Here is what the script looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

printlist=/u/lawson/stage/Scripts/printdirs.txt
archivelist=/u/lawson/stage/Scripts/archivedirs.txt

# Checking the archive list and moving files

for i in $(cat $printlist) ; do
    cd $i   
    /usr/bin/find . -mtime +14 -type f -exec mv "{}" $(cat $archivelist) \;

done
```

Here is what the text files contain:

```
$ cat printdirs.txt
/u/lawson/law/print/lawson/tim/1
/u/lawson/law/print/dgfinance/monday190/1

$ cat archivedirs.txt
/u/lawson/law/print/archive
/u/lawson/law/print/archive2
```

How can I get the script to loop for each corresponding line and not copy the "archive" folder into the "archive2" folder?

UPDATE: Updated the script with terdon's help. Here is the output after adding the echo command:

```
# ./printarchive2.ksh 
/usr/bin/find /u/lawson/law/prin -mtime +14 -type f -exec mv /lawson/tim/1      /u/lawson/law/print/archive {} +
/usr/bin/find /u/lawson/law/prin -mtime +14 -type f -exec mv /dgfinance/monday190/1     /u/lawson/law/print/archive2 {} +
```

The script terdon wanted me to use is removing the "t" from the directory paths. I tested it out by changing the "t" to an "n". It removed the letter "n" from my directory paths. Is there another way to signify a tab field separator that Korn shell can read because apparently this does not work in KSH.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `paste` here. It's a nifty tool that can be used to combine files:

```
$ paste printdirs.txt archivedirs.txt 
/u/lawson/law/print/lawson/tim/1    /u/lawson/law/print/archive
/u/lawson/law/print/dgfinance/monday190/1   /u/lawson/law/print/archive2
```

As you can see above, it will print successive lines from both files, separated by tabs. The tab-separation is very useful if your directory names can contain spaces. Now, you can iterate over the `paste` output to do your thing:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

printlist="/u/lawson/stage/Scripts/printdirs.txt"
archivelist="/u/lawson/stage/Scripts/archivedirs.txt"

paste "$printlist" "$archivelist" | while IFS=$'\t' read source dest; do
    /usr/bin/find "$source" -mtime +14 -type f -exec mv -t "$dest" {}  +
done
```

Note that I i) removed the `cd`, there's no need for it, `find` can be run on the target from anywhere; ii) removed the `for i in $(cat foo)` syntax, that should generally be avoided and iii) replaced `-exec ... \;` with `-exec +` which is more efficient (it will try and combine `mv` calls, which is why the `-t "$dest"` is needed).

If your `mv` doesn't support the `-t` option, change the `find` command back to:

```
/usr/bin/find "$source" -mtime +14 -type f -exec mv "$source" "$dest" \;
```

Comment: I ran the script. Here is my output:

# ./printarchive2.ksh 
find: bad status-- /u/lawson/law/prin
find: cannot execute :: No such file or directory
find: bad status-- /u/lawson/law/prin
find: cannot execute :: No such file or directory

Comment: @UncleJayRazz does `/u/lawson/law/print` exist?

Comment: (1) Don't quote `{}` in `find` commands.  (2) The `-t` option of `mv` is a GNU-ism.

Comment: @SatoKatsura 1) D'oh! Thanks, copied that directly from the OP; 2) Fair enough, answer edited.

Comment: @terdon There is no directory called "/u/lawson/law/prin". It should be "/u/lawson/law/print". What is removing the "t" in print from the script?

Comment: And shouldn't the source directory be the first line in the $printlist file?

Comment: @UncleJayRazz nothing that I can see, it works fine here. Are you sure the `t` is actually there in the file? And yes, the source directory is the 1st line in $printlist. Try adding an `echo` in front of the `find` command (make it `echo  /usr/bin/find "$source" -mtime +14 -type f -exec mv -t "$dest" {}  +`) and run the script again. Add the output to your question. That way we can see what's going on.